# JavaScript, radiobutton.checked not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am using a bit of JavaScript to check an HTML form to see if the user has selected a radio button. It is working wonderfully in Chrome, FireFox, and Safari, but not in IE (tried ie9 and ie11 on different machines).

Here is a link to the page (it's for a school assignment so all the code is easily visible in the source) so you can look at the code and see it work in Chrome and see what happens in IE. http://lampbusters.com/bellerose/javascript/form.html
(the form submits to a simple echo php script, so you don't have to worry about it sending anywhere or saving any information.)

For those who don't want to follow the link, here is the code:

```
window.onload = setupEvents;
function setupEvents() {
document.getElementById('contactForm').onsubmit = checkForm;
}

function checkForm () {
var shootType = document.contactForm.shootType
var shootInstruct = document.getElementById('shootInstruct')
var checkOne = false;
var i;
for (i in shootType) {
  if (shootType[i].checked) {
    checkOne = true;
  }
}
  if (checkOne != true) {
    alert("Please tell me what kind of photography shoot you're interested in.");
    shootInstruct.style.color = "#FF0000";
    shootInstruct.style.fontSize = "1.2em";
    shootInstruct.style.fontWeight = "Bold";
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

shootType is referencing about 6 radio buttons with the same "name" attribute in HTML, so that it basically functions as an array. As you can see, this simply runs through that array, checks if one is checked, then submits the form if one is checked or doesn't submit if one isn't. Working perfectly in all other browsers, but in IE it never submits, even if a radio button is checked. As I'm just learning js I'm not sure which part of this is unsupported by IE and haven't had much luck googling the issue. Anyone have an idea why this isn't working in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use *for..in* on lists, use a standard for loop. In IE, lists have other enumerable properties you don't expect:

```js
var controls = document.forms[0].r;
for (var p in controls) document.write('"' + p + '"<br>');
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="r">
  <input type="radio" name="r">
  <input type="radio" name="r">
  <input type="radio" name="r">
</form>
```